# Worklight - invoking push notification adapter from non-worklight applications using a URL

Tags: websphere, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I had posted an issue last year and received a solution on this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=453422&start=15&tstart=0)

This solution of adding security test `wl_unprotected` in the adapter XML worked on WL server 5.0.0.3.

However, after a recent upgrade to 5.0.0.5 with Websphere Server 8.5, we are getting an authentication error when invoking the WL Adapters using a direct URL invocation.

URL:

```
http://IPAddress:9080/worklight/invoke?adapter=MyPushNotificationAdapter&procedure=submitNotification&parameters=['user1','id1','1']
```

Response:

```
/*-secure-
{"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"errors":["Work Light Authentication: null"],"info":[]}*/
```

Even when we remove the `wl_unprotected` security test from the adapter XML, the error persists. Kindly advise on a solution for invoking the adapter directly using  URL in WL 5.0.0.5 Enterprise Edition server.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the securityTest="wl_unprotected" to your adapter procedure should still work in 5.0.5.

I just tested it by creating a new Worklight 5.0.5 project, hybrid app and adapter. The default adapter created has 2 procedures by default, getStories and getStoriesFiltered.

I added the securityTest="wl_unprotected" to the getStories procedure in the adapter XML file, but left it off of the getStoriesFiltered procedure. Then I built the adapter and deployed it to a 5.0.5 Worklight server running on WebSphere Liberty.

When I invoked the getStoriesFiltered procedure (which did not have securityTest="wl_unprotected") using curl, the call failed with the same error you described.

But when I invoked the getStories procedure (which had the securityTest="wl_unprotected"), it was successful.

For reference, here is the Technote that describes using the "wl_unprotected" securityTest for just this scenario: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21612594

Comment: We are running Worklight server 5.0.5 on WebSphere Application Server 8.5 (not Liberty Profile) Could this be the cause of it not working ?

Comment: Could you please confirm if this works for a push notification adapter procedure in a production server setup ? Our adapter procedure uses an Event Source that sends out notifications to subscribed users. We consistently get the authentication failure when accessing the push notification procedure using the URL. Note that the same URL invocation of the adapter procedure works fine in the 5.0.5 development environment.

Comment: I would not expect that using WebSphere Application Server 8.5 vs. the WebSphere Liberty profile to make any different in regards to this issue.

I also tried using the Module 41 Push Notifications sample on Worklight 5.0.5 on Liberty. I was able to access the URL directly as long as I specified the "wl_unprotected" securityTest for the submitNotification procedure in the adapter XML.

Answer (score 1):

There was another adapter procedure being invoked within the PushNotification adapter procedure. After I added the "wl_unprotected" security test to the second adapter procedure as well, the URL invocation of Push notifications started working. Thanks !